# JsonSerializer not using internal constructor during deserialization

Tags: c#, .net-core, system.text.json, .net-6.0

I'm writing a library to access a web API used to manage data in the backend system.
The library will also provide classes with logic to properly manage the data.
For this reason most of the classes cannot have public setters for properties or a public constructor that accepts all the properties. Instead I'm trying to use a constructor with internal access modifier that can set all the properties.

When trying to deserialize a JSON string using [System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0) it will ignore the internal constructor - it will either use some other constructor or throw an exception. I've also tried annotating the internal constructor with `[JsonConstructor]` but it does nothing.

Example class with internal constructor:

```
public class Entry
{
    public int Id { get; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }


    [JsonConstructor]
    internal Entry(int id, string name, string value)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Name = name;
        this.Value = value;
    }
}
```

Suppose the user can use the library to get an `Entry` from the backend, modify its name and value, and update it. User should not be able to change the `Id` property or create a new `Entry`.

Example deserialization:

```
var json = "{\"id\": 1337, \"name\": \"TestEntry\", \"value\": \"TestValue\"}";
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions(JsonSerializerDefaults.Web);

var entry = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Entry>(json, options);
```

Calling `JsonSerializer.Deserialize` will throw `System.NotSupportedException` - Deserialization of types without a parameterless constructor, a singular parameterized constructor, or a parameterized constructor annotated with 'JsonConstructorAttribute' is not supported:

A possible solution is to just make the constructor public and annotate it with `[Obsolete("Message", true)]` attribute - when trying to use this constructor the compiler will throw and error, making the constructor unusable.
But I feel this is not the most elegant solution and it also misuses the `[Obsolete]` attribute.

Is there any other way of solving this problem?

Comment: Where do you get the json string to begin with? If the class is internal then it is not meant to be exposed externally. You likely need a DTO to map to and from

Comment: Internal constructors are not supported in System.Text.Json. Please check the documentation. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-immutability?pivots=dotnet-6-0

Comment: Remember that reflection can always be used to overcome limitations you place in the public interface, so someone who is sufficiently determined *can* change the ID of an object -- never rely on the interface for enforcing security boundaries. Given that, it's usually better to give people access to public constructors that initialize objects consistently without worrying about who's calling the constructors. Verifying the data should be done at a later stage (and never skipped). Of course properties should still be immutable where appropriate, to prevent preventable mistakes.

Comment: @arynaq JSON comes from web API (using HttpClient and GetFromJsonAsync extension method). The class is external. It seems like using DTOs is the way to go, although I was hoping to use a more "direct" approach.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Sure, reflection can always bypass stuff, and as you mentioned, the proper checks are done on the backend. What I'm trying to do is limit the amount of mistakes when using the library - communicating to other developers which properties are immutable and which can be updated.

Comment: Communicating immutability is independent from the constructor, though -- that's done by just, well, making them immutable. :P To make a mistake, a developer would need to explicitly construct a new object and copy over the properties of the old object while using a new ID -- and that clearly reflects what the operation would truly be, which is creating a new thing. Which presumably isn't allowed to be done that way, and would be caught by the backend (because someone could always forge either objects or requests). Removing the constructor is a fairly "expensive" solution that hinders tests.

Answer (score 2):

In this case the best way to achieve this would be by using a separate model for serialization. And then using an internal constructor on the Domain model.

````
public class EntryDto
{
    public int Id { get; }

    public string Name { get;  }
    public string Value { get; }


    [JsonConstructor]
    public EntryDto(int id, string name, string value)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Name = name;
        this.Value = value;
    }
    
    public Entry ToDomainModel()
    {
      return new Entry(this.Id, this.Name, this.Value);
    }

}

public class Entry
{
    public int Id { get; }

    public string Name { get; }
    public string Value { get; }

    internal Entry(int id, string name, string value)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Name = name;
        this.Value = value;
    }
}

```
````

Answer (score 1):

Had this when I ported an old Azure Function from .Net Core to .Net6.0 and started using the `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker` instead of the .core `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask` files for the function Orchestrators.

when using `Microsoft.DurableTask.Client` Version="1.2.0" i got the same mentioned exception, when trying to de-serialise this passed class\object parameter

*System.NotSupportedException - Deserialization of types without a parameterless constructor, a singular parameterized constructor, or a parameterized constructor annotated with 'JsonConstructorAttribute' is not supported:*

**IN ESSENSE**

`Microsoft.Extensions.Azure` Version="1.5.0" seems to handle the de-serialisation fine even with unsupported types as per MS: [Supported key Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/supported-collection-types?pivots=dotnet-6-0#supported-key-types)

issue was when passing the `detail` object to the OrchestratorActivity possibly trying to de-serialize to `FunctionContext` for that method,

```
    var result = await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("EngineRun", detail);
    outputs.Add(result);
}

[Function("EngineRun")]
public async Task<string> EngineRun([ActivityTrigger] FunctionContext detail)
```

This is the `detail` object in question:

```
public class engineRun
{
    public string batchid { get; set; }
    public string taskid { get; set; }
    public string? saleid { get; set; }
    public int stage { get; set; }
    public ServiceClient? service { get; set; }
}
```

Hopes this helps - kept me busy for a while.

**Edit**
to confirm even (braking all the rules) below still works and using `System.Text.Json` with `Microsoft.Extensions.Azure` :

```
[JsonPolymorphic]
public class engineRun
{
    private bool _started;
    [JsonConstructor]
    public engineRun() { }
    public engineRun(bool started)
    {
        _started = started;
    }
    public string batchid { get; set; }
    public string taskid { get; set; }
    public string? saleid { get; set; }
    public int stage { get; set; }
    public ServiceClient? service { get; set; }
    public bool Started
    {
        get { return _started; }
        private set { value = _started; }
    }
}
```